# Access Cosmos DB using VNet from another tenant

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We have a Cosmos DB with restricted firewall access to specific VNets.
We are looking for a way to enable access to the DB for a VNet that is not in the same tenant (i.e. cross-tenant).
However, when attempting to add an existing virtual network to the whitelist, it is only providing a possibility to choose a VNet from the current tenant.
[image: CosmosDbNetworkingSettingView]

**Is there a way to whitelist a VNet from another tenant?**

Comment: You need to setup a Point to Site or Site to Site VPN between the tenancies, or add a public IP to your VNet

Comment: This would be a better fit on [sf], since it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear if you own the other tenant or not, but as @Chris Schaller said in the comments, you need to setup a VPN in order to connect a VNET to another VNET from different tenants.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-vnet-vnet-resource-manager-portal